# ASP.NET setting up membershipprovider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have created a registration and a login form by using a wizard. But when someone registers and tries to login, they can't. I've come to understand that this because there is no membershipprovider. I created both my forms and my database automatically, Shouldn't there be a default membershipprovider then? is there a way to find out the name/settings of a possible membershipprovider?

I tried to set up a membershipprovider myself with:

```
  <membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
      <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="MembershipADProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SQLMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ASPNETDBConnectionString" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
  </membership>
```

In the web.config file, but i just get an error that there is no default membershipprovider when i open the registration page. I also see there is a membershipprovider option in the registerform properties, but i don't get any successes here either.

Comment: When you said you created it automatically, do you mean you ran the Aspnet_regsql command? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx

Comment: No i didn't. I mean I used the wizards. I've came across that command while searching for an answer but since i already have a working database etc. i can't use that anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Add a default provider:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
```

Comment: Oh, i did that (i'll edit the code), but there's no difference. I register go to login, it seems that the login works, but when i press on my profile link, it asks to login again. When i use a member that i created through the asp.net configuration website, everything works. (i'll edit my code with your suggestion). What should I write in the membershipprovider property of the registration form? (the options bottom right on the page)

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line:

```
 <membership>
```

to:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
```

Comment: I did that, but there is no difference. I'm completely blocked by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Always set the "applicationName" property when configuring ASP.NET 2.0 Membership and other Providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx)

Comment: Should i add applicationName within the add tag?

Comment: added the applicationName, no difference.

Comment: Like this: applicationName="/" or like this: applicationName="/appName"?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed. There was a membershipprovider, but new members didn't get the member role when they registered.